# Select entries from MySQL by URL with spaces

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Making a little script that searches for existing combinations of words. Getting AJAX with script.php?req=%param% where %param% is entry in DB.
For single requests it works fine, returns next value as I need. But I simply can not understand how to find entries that are divided by space:

```
$REQUEST = isset( $_GET['req'] )? $_GET['req']: false;
echo $REQUEST;
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "1337", "database");
$query = "SELECT `first_col` , `second_col` FROM `table` WHERE `first_col` =  '" . $REQUEST . "'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$pieces = explode(", ", $row['second_col']); //explodes given data using comma and space
echo $pieces['0']; //prints out first part of req output
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
```

But when I request some kind of this:

> ?req=word+another_word

script returns nothing as it can't find such entry "word another_word". It must print out with spaces, not commas.

How do I find all of the entries per table and print them out in one string without commas, divided by spaces only?

Comment: Please don't use mysql_ functions anymore (use mysqli_ or better PDO) and escape your input in the query.

Comment: @davely, switched code to mysqli, thank you. But still I have to use this input method (by the URL).

Comment: Can you explain which rows you want to select? From your example, you are looking for specific words in the first_col, and showing only a piece of second_col as output. What kind of data is in these columns?

Comment: @Aioros, I am looking for same word in first_col as in the URL request and then script outputs first catched entry from second_col's output. There are VARCHAR textentries (words).

Comment: Ok, but is there a row having "word another_word" as first_col, or are you trying to get data from a row having "word" and another having "another_word"?

Comment: @Aioros, that's the case. In a row I have only "word" and in another row I have "another_word". Search query will look like "word another_word"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you should try something like this. Basically, you use the keyword IN in your query, so you prepare a list of words. After that, you loop through the results.

```
$REQUEST = isset( $_GET['req'] )? $_GET['req']: false;
echo $REQUEST;
$words = "'" . str_replace(" ", "','", $REQUEST) . "'"; // you will have something like: 'word','another_word','etc'

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "1337", "database");
$query = "SELECT `first_col`, `second_col`
          FROM `table`
          WHERE `first_col` IN  (" . $words .")
          ORDER BY FIELD(first_col, $words)";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$output = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $pieces = explode(", ", $row['second_col']); //explodes given data using comma and space
    $output[] = $pieces['0']; // adds first part of req output to the output array
}

$result->free();
$mysqli->close();

echo implode(" ", $output);
```

Comment: Seems working, but it reverses input strings and I can't figure out how to split output data by spaces. Explode/Implode doesn't work well.

Comment: What do you mean by "reverses input strings"? As for the split by spaces, I don't know what your data in second_col look like. An example of table rows and desired output would really help.

Comment: for example, input is "?req=word+other_word". It will be "word other_word" in correct state. When it is being processed by this script, it seems, all the data taken from second_col is reversed.
This is how it looks:
first_col | second_col
word      | wordvaule1
other_word| wordvalue2

And I thought it would output as wordvalue1wordvaule2, but it came out as wordvalue2wordvalue1 and this can't be divided somewhy.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer adding the ORDER BY clause and a space between the echoed words. You can obviously do whatever you want to do with those words inside the while loop and/or after it.

Comment: oh, there it goes! Thank you very much, it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

IF it's only the '+' you want to replace by a space use `str_replace()`:

```
$REQUEST = isset( $_GET['req'] )? str_replace('+', ' ', $_GET['req']): false;
```

And please escape your input:

```
$query = "SELECT `first_col` , `second_col` FROM `table` WHERE `first_col` =  '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($REQUEST) . "'";
```

Comment: Well, there is a misunderstanding. I'm searching for these two entries in database. Input is already changed from + to space. But I simply can't figure out how to search in DB by given entry with space ("1 2"), but input like "1" will be found.